# React Router v4 Nested Routing not working when in sub level

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router, react-router-dom

I'm trying to build a React App, this is the first time i'm working with react and so i don't know how to troubleshoot this. Basically what i need is to create routes for a link, let's say these are the following links.

```
/car
/car/sedan
/car/coupe
```

i have setup routing as so.

car.js

```
import React from 'react'
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route, Link } from 'react-router-dom'
import CoupeCar from './coupecar'
import SedanCar from './sedancar'

class Car extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
    }

    render () {
        return (
            <div className="main_elem_container">
                <Router>
                    <Switch>
                        <Route path="/car" component={Car} />
                        <Route exact path="/car/sedan" component={SedanCar} />
                        <Route exact path="/car/coupe" component={CoupeCar} />
                    </Switch>
                </Router>
            </div>
        );  
    }
}

const Car = () => (
    <p>I'm a Car</p>
)

export default Car;
```

And the routing works i can visit `/car/sedan` and `/car/coupe` when i'm browsing through the navigation from `/car` but i cannot visit `/car/sedan` when im at the `/car/coupe` page and vice-versa.

The navigation just gets stuck and doesn't load, please let me know on how i can fix this i've even tried many options but all of them give me this result, at least if i knew how to debug this it'll be better, thanks.

Comment: Try putting the more general `"/car"`route below the other two.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how your setup works partially, it should not with this config. What you need is:

```
<Router>
    <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/car" component={Car} />
        <Route path="/car/sedan" component={SedanCar} />
        <Route path="/car/coupe" component={CoupeCar} />
    </Switch>
</Router>
```

So, if only when you hit /car your Car component renders. For /car/sedan and /car/coupe you will see the related components. If you don't use `exact` for /car, /car/sedan and /car/coupe will render Car component no matter what.

Also, do not use same component names. You have two Car components. Rename the container something else, App maybe?

Comment: Well actually im using React-Redux so maybe that might have something to do with it. I've tried your code by including exact in `/car` only and not the rest and also i've changed the names to something different now, but it still gives the same result.

I can visit `/car/sedan` from `/car` but not from something in it's own level like clicking a link from `/car/sedan` to `/car/coupe`. Thanks

Comment: react-redux is not related with this problem. See a working example: https://codesandbox.io/s/5xoqoly65x

Answer (score 0):

try this, the exact path should be placed as last option

```
<Router>
    <Switch>
        <Route path="/car/sedan" component={SedanCar} />
        <Route path="/car/coupe" component={CoupeCar} />
        <Route exact path="/car" component={Car} />
    </Switch>
</Router>
```